# Use XML source code formatting as default for XSL-FO questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, code-formatting

[xsl-fo](/questions/tagged/xsl-fo) questions usually contain [xsl](/questions/tagged/xsl) and/or [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) source code. It would probably make sense to set `XML` as the default source code language for questions tagged with [xsl-fo](/questions/tagged/xsl-fo). See an example here:

[Put XSL-FO block on next page instead of splitting it across pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655999/put-xsl-fo-block-on-next-page-instead-of-splitting-it-across-pages)

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Quickest fix ever! Thanks :-)